# How to unit test java multiple thread

Tags: java, multithreading, unit-testing, callback

The issue is that I have a method starting a new thread for a time-consuming work. I want to test the callback result, but the child thread may still running, so as a result, what I get is not the right stub.
I think the code may explain itself:

```
public class JustAClass {
    //it is a callback for async   
    public interface JustACallBack {
        void callFunc(JustAResult result);
    }

    //this is the result interface
    public interface JustAResult {
    }

    //this is a real class for the interface
    public class JustAResultReal implements JustAResult{
        public JustAResultReal(String content) {this.content = content;}
        public String content;
    }

    //here is the key function
    public void threadFunc(final JustACallBack callBack) {
        BCCache.executorService.execute(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                //just to simulate a time-consuming task
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(1000);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                //now we callback
                callBack.callFunc(new JustAResultReal("can you reach me"));
            }
        });
    }
}
```

and the test function could be(I am using `mockito`):

```
@Test
public void testThreadFunc() throws Exception {

    JustAClass justAClass = new JustAClass();

    JustAClass.JustACallBack callBack = Mockito.mock(JustAClass.JustACallBack.class);

    justAClass.threadFunc(callBack);

    //add this line, we can get the expected result
    Thread.sleep(1200);

    Mockito.verify(callBack).callFunc(captor.capture());

    System.out.println(((JustAClass.JustAResultReal)captor.getValue()).content);
}
```

I know we can add a `sleep` to wait and expect that the child thread would exit within the period, but could there be a better way? Actually how could I know how long the child thread would take? Setting a very long time can be an approach but just seems not very nice.

Comment: IMO: I would remove the threading aspect from the unit test myself and test the logic inside the thread only. I have faith that threading in Java works, I don't need to test that. And testing how the threading of the logic works with respect to the code you run in parallel to is part of an integration test, not a unit test.

Comment: The problem is, you are using a static ExecutorService.  To make things more unit-testy, you could pass in a _mock_ ExecutorService, and then verify that the module under test interacted with the mock in the expected way.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with threading in a unit test if threading is *the point* of the code you're testing. See my answer on how to do this correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I aggree with @Gimbys comment about this is no longer a unit-test when you start testing the the threading aspect.

Nevertheless it is interesting as a way to integration-test a asynchronous invokation.

To avvoid sleep i tend to use the class [CountDownLatch](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CountDownLatch.html) to wait for invokations. 
In order to count down you need an actuall implementation of the callback interface - so in my example I have made a mock implementation of this.

Since there is no actual methods to fetch the data - i am just testing that it is in fact a instance of the JustAReal interface.

```
@Test
public void testInvoke() throws Exception {

    final CountDownLatch countDownLatch = new CountDownLatch(1); //1 is how many invokes we are waiting for

    JustAClass justAClass = new JustAClass();
    JustAClass.JustACallBack callBack = new JustAClass.JustACallBack() {
        @Override
        public void callFunc(final JustAClass.JustAResult result) {
            assertNotNull("Result should not be null", result);
            assertTrue("Result should be instance of JustAResultReal", result instanceof JustAClass.JustAResultReal);
            countDownLatch.countDown();
        }
    };

    justAClass.threadFunc(callBack);
    if(!countDownLatch.await(1200, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)){
        fail("Timed out, see log for errors");
    }

}
```

Comment: This approach actually doesn't work since any assertions failures are never noticed by the main test thread.

Comment: You are right, the assertion fails will probably be in the log - and we need to check if the latch has counted down correctly to make the test fail like: `if(!countDownLatch.await(1200, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)){
            fail("Timed out");
        }` I will update the answer.

Answer (score 2):

The general approach in @stalet's answer is close, but doesn't quite work since any assertion failures from a separate thread are not noticed by the main thread. Therefore your test will **always** pass, even when it shouldn't. Instead, try using [ConcurrentUnit](https://github.com/jhalterman/concurrentunit) (which I authored):

```
@Test
public void testInvoke() throws Throwable {
    Waiter waiter = new Waiter();
    JustAClass justAClass = new JustAClass();
    JustAClass.JustACallBack callBack = new JustAClass.JustACallBack() {
        @Override
        public void callFunc(final JustAClass.JustAResult result) {
            waiter.assertNotNull(result);
            waiter.assertTrue(result instanceof JustAClass.JustAResultReal);
            waiter.resume();
        }
    };

    justAClass.threadFunc(callBack);
    waiter.await(1200, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
}
```

The key here is ConcurrentUnit's `Waiter` will properly report any assertions failures to the main test thread and the test will pass or fail as it should.

Comment: Does this api interrupt the main thread immediately?. If you have `waiter.await(10, TimeUnit.MINUTES)` you wont have to wait more than necessary if  the test has allready failed ?

Comment: @stalet Yep, failed assertions or `waiter.resume()` calls will interrupt the awaiting main thread immediately. If a failure occurred, it will be re-thrown automatically allowing the test to fail as expected.

Comment: Yeah. Well then this is obviously better. +1 :)